# Response Download Header - No Cache - Must-Revalidate

Tags: php, laravel, validation, caching, header

I would like to download files from a controller method with:

```
public function ....(...){
   .....
   return response()->download(....);
}
```

But without cache, the function must re-validate the content and download a fresh download.

I tried many different things like:

```
return response()->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate')
return response()->download(..)->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate')
```

and none of that is working. The laravel responses docs doesn't show a proper way to do this from a controller response, it only does it from middleware/web https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution as follows:**

```
return response()->download(..file.., 
        ['Cache-Control' => 'no-cache, must-revalidate']);
```

The **Method Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory** function looks like the following, and takes an array of headers:

```
/**
 * Create a new file download response.
 *
 * @param  \SplFileInfo|string  $file
 * @param  string|null  $name
 * @param  array  $headers
 * @param  string|null  $disposition
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse
 */
public function download($file, $name = null, array $headers = [], $disposition = 'attachment')
{
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($file, 200, $headers, true, $disposition);

    if (! is_null($name)) {
        return $response->setContentDisposition($disposition, $name, $this->fallbackName($name));
    }

    return $response;
}
```